# How to get Author's avatar image in the Blog Module of Divi theme?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am using Divi Theme in WordPress and trying to show Author's avatar image in Blog (Grid Layout) Module along with other information.

However, the default options in Divi only let me show the Author name, but no avatar image.

[This is the default structure of Divi Blog Grid Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pe7j.png).

I am [trying to achieve this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMw9m.png).

**What I tried till now:**

1. I [found this solution](https://divisoup.com/add-author-avatar-divi-blog/) on internet and followed everything. Created child theme with custom module too. But it **doesn't work
   properly**.

Can anyone help me?